# Positioning inside section with height:100% and width:100%

Tags: html, css

How can I properly position the 'portfolio' section so that it doesn't go behind 'contact' section and that it stretches and shrinks depending on the size of the screen (just like the photo backgrounds)??? Can it be done with CSS and percantages only??? I tried many different combinations but w/o success.

The height of each section is always 100%. So is the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwwve/9/

```
<section id="home" class="photobg">
        <div class="inner">
                <div class="copy">
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                    <p>Some text here!</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough idea: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/zwwve/17/

For unhiding the portfolio section, put a div wrap around it. No CSS for the wrap required.

For the scaling, you will want to remove the gallery width. Maybe put a min-width.

```
.gallery {
    min-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

For the portfolio hovers, you can also give them a percentage and a min-width.

```
.project {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 120px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Its rough, but the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you. This is a progress when it comes to scaling but my portfolio section is still behind the contact section. This drives me crazy :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/zwwve/17/  You may want to decrease the size of the portfolio items. Maybe giving them a min and max width.

Comment: I see you added min a max width which improves this a lot. Is it possible to add a percentage values to #pagetwo height and width? The greyish frame can be smaller than the white container of the portfolio section. It's ok as long as the greyish frame sticks inside the portfolio's white section.

Comment: When I add #pagetwo{height:50%;} property I totally lose the grey container!?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/zwwve/25/ Yep, add height: 100% and display: inline-block; to #pagetwo

Comment: I just changed the width of #pagetwo to 80% so it looks nicer now. But the grey/dark container is still out of portfolio section and behind contact section :(

Comment: With this specific design, I think the only way to avoid the items being hidden in a container with 100% height is to give it a min-width to the entire design and a min-height to the portfolio wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/zwwve/34/

Comment: But now the portfolio section is over 100% of the browser 's size and I woud really like to have all sections with 100% height so that the content of each section fits nicely inside the screen size weather it's a mobile, desktop or widescreen... Alright. Thanks a lot for help so far.

Answer (score 0):

You had a fixed width for the .gallery class which I changed to 100%, now the projects fall underneath each other as the screen size decreases.

I also changed the position and bottom of the contact div so it can be at the bottom.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/zwwve/19/)

Added/Changed CSS:

```
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#contact{
    position: relative;
    top: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting involved here. I checked your fiddle but now the portfolio section is too big and it doesn't follow the browser size when I stretch or shrink it (like it does with the home page for example :(